# How Do I Fill In The Festival Plaza Questionnaires?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

When I communicate with guests who appear in my Festival Plaza, I select "Let me see how you are doing" and switch to the next page to bring up the 'Questionnaires" page. Questions include "Where do you fit in your family?", "Which Pokemon region is your favourite?" etc.

None of the questions that appear in this screen are available through the profile option in the Festival Plaza menu and none of the NPCs available to me seem to allow me to fill in the questionnaire. How do you change the answers from "No idea"?

Comment: I literally just got asked one of the questions by a guest in Festival Plaza. Perhaps you cannot answer these questions unless asked by guests? Though I cannot see my own answers.

Comment: So far I have been asked several of these questions by guests, though I cannot see my own answers still so I cannot confirm if this is the correct/only method to fill in the questionnaires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Questionnaires:**
>
> The whisper "Tell me! Tell me!" comprises 16 different requests, all of which are questionnaires the player must answer. Each request has a number of custom responses, as well as a standard "No comment" response. If the player answers "No comment", they will not receive Festival Coins and the request will be exhausted. Any other answer is rewarded.
> These questionnaires are always asked in order. That is, if two people are whispering "Tell me! Tell me!", whichever person is asked first will ask the next question. After the player answers the last questionnaire, the next requestor will start with the first questionnaire again.
> The player's responses to these questionnaires appear in their profile when they are visitors to other players' Festival Plazas.

Found on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Festival_Plaza#Questionnaires)

Comment: You need to add a link to the page and quote whatever you took from the page. Just attributing to a site doesn't count. Also, this is extremely hard to read and needs to be reformatted.

Comment: I've found the details on Bulbapedia and updated @Policeman_Fives answer with the link. There is no mention of being able to view your own answers, so I guess once you've given an answer, that's it.